# Tab-Index while reviewing and editing a question is not set properly

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

While I am reviewing the Q&A and editing them, that time Tab Index is not properly set. If you have done editing the Question or Answer and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> that will leads us to the next available link but not to the textbox (Question Title/Comment and Suggestion Section/ Tags) which is available just above that link.

So I suggest it should be in proper order so that while using <kbd>Tab</kbd> you will be navigated to the next possible element, i.e. Comment/Tags/Title Section.